# Deleted 16GB MySQL log file, no space freed

Tags: disk-usage, rm

I deleted a 16GB MYSQL log file via the command line:

```
sudo rm /var/log/mysql/slow.log
```

but the space has not been freed. Is there some sort of flush I need to run?

Comment: Did you reboot meanwhile since deletion? MAybe the file is still in use by something.

Comment: I cannot restart the system as its in use all the time. The large file was either the MySQL slow query log or the iptables.log. I can't remember which, both programs are still running.

Comment: then those files will further exists untill either the logrotation hits or the system is rebooted, linux works like this which in most cases is good.

Answer (score 0):

Per Videonauth suggestion, this can be remedied by rotating the MySQL logs:

```
logrotate -vf /etc/logrotate.d/mysql-server
```